# How to do ip spoofing/change source address/raw socket programming for UDP packets in java?

Tags: java, linux, networking, raw-sockets, spoofing

I sent and received spoofed IP packets by using Linux kali tools hping3. Now I would like to send spoofed IP packets using java. I looked at these questions but could not find any good resource(existing links don't work) or working solution.

- [How to fake source ip-address of a udp-packet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493384/how-to-fake-source-ip-address-of-a-udp-packet)
- [Spoof source IP/Port with DatagramPacket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626262/spoof-source-ip-port-with-datagrampacket)
- [Creating raw packets to spoof UDP Packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650825/creating-raw-packets-to-spoof-udp-packets)
- [How to Spoof ip in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204967/how-to-spoof-ip-in-java)

Most of them have accepted answers but those answers solution do not work now. Most of those answers' solution links don't work like these links.

- http://jnetpcap.com/
- http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/JpcapSender.html
- http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc/

Additional information.
My PC is Linux server(64 bit) and with 64 bit JDK. One solution worked for windows but does not work in Linux.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with their website, but jnetpcap is (was?) a solid Java wrapper for libpcap. I used it a few times. Maybe there are versions and examples still floating around.

Comment: I have a working version in windows but no matter how much i try i have not been able to make it work in linux 64bit pc.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out there was a problem in Jnetpcap 1.4 for Linux OS. Jnetpcap 1.4 worked fine in windows but did not work in Linux but Jnetpcap 1.3 worked fine both in windows and Linux.